# SourceTree - Reverse Commit & Push

Tags: git, github, atlassian-sourcetree

I am using SourceTree for version control. I recently created a branch on GitHub but I forgot to switch to that branch and instead pushed my changes to the wrong branch.

So I did a reverse commit in SourceTree, however now my local is 1 ahead. And the commit is still on GitHub in the wrong branch.

Can anyone tell me how I can resolve this please?

Answer (score 1):

Checkout your new branch. Cherry-pick the commit:

```
git cherry-pick [commit hash]
```

Then just delete the other branch (assuming that you've pushed).

```
git branch -D [branch name]
```

If you need the deleted branch just check it out from origin again. If you haven't pushed the other branch, check it out again and do a hard reset to the previous commit:

```
git reset --hard [commit hash]
```